# Existence of compact Hausdorff space that is not sequentially compact without Choice

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We know the two famous examples of a compact Hausdorff space that is not sequentially compact: $[0,1]^{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})}$, $\beta\mathbb{N}$. But both of the proofs that they are compact use the Axiom of Choice. Is there an example that does not need AC?